# I moved a new program into my bin folder, but nothing happens when I try to run it

Tags: bash, shell

I have two identical files in my `~/bin` folder, test and test2. Both just print a string. One works; the other, which I just put in there today, doesn't. In fact nothing happens at all, which is odd. Do I need to refresh the path or something? How do I get it to recognize this new program in `~/bin`?

(I'm running it just by typing "test" from anywhere, although I did try typing it from within the bin directory too.)

---

Solved. This is apparently a problem with having a program named "test". I copied it to "test3" and it works. In fact anything but "test" works.

Comment: The output is "test". The output of test2, though, is "/home/me/bin/test2".

Comment: `test` is a built-in command. Unfortunate perhaps but that's how it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume `test` doesn't work. The reason is, test is a shell builtin. Try running

```
$ type test2
> test2 is /home/user/bin/test2

$ type test
> test is a shell builtin
```

The `test` shell builtin is used to test conditions, e.g.:

```
if test "x" = "x"; then
    echo yeah
fi
```

The reason why this isn't used often anymore, is that it can also be written by using `[`:

```
if [ "x" = "x" ]; then
    echo yeah
fi
```

Comment: I just figured this out myself.

Comment: @felwithe if you really want to have a program named test, call it with the full or relative path -- ~/bin/test or /home/user/bin/test or (cd ~/bin; ./test)

Comment: @JeffSchaller I don't, "test" is just my default and I was trying some things today. Calling it directly did work, but I was testing the way the bin directory acted specifically.